# rating, share and review issue for single WooCommerce page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i am new WooCommerce, i am having one issue for product single page. which is rating and sharing not showing. i want to show in single page rating, sharing and review count number.

bellow **content-single-product.php** code

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>



</div>
```

this way rating and share not coming. but this is default code.

i do that in my function for reorder hooked

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 40 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
```

still now showing. i check in generate html code. nothing i see class/id/div rating and sharing html

but my shop(product) page thumbnail rating show. i add costume start rating which is

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'get_star_rating' );
function get_star_rating()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();

    echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
}
```

this is working find one product page. i want add this start rating and shearing button in my single page and want to review count .. example attached image [image]

i think for sharing for have plugins. if you guys any recommended plugins for sharing please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to give you some cleanup solution which is basic code setup.

**For social share:**
See plugin [Social Sharing Toolkit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-sharing-toolkit) Which is easy sharing and connecting on social networks. Display on posts or use widgets or *shortcode*. Also Twitter *name/hashtag* to link converter.

`use do_shortcode('[social_share]')` for display social share anywhere on site. In *woocoomrce* Product page use this code in `content-single-product.php` file.

**For Star rating:**
There is a sort logic here for if you need star rating at your single product, then you will need to do template editing.

Edit your `/x/woocommerce/single-product/rating.php` and add this code before `?>`

```
GLOBAL $product; echo '<div class="star-rating-container aggregate">' . $product->get_rating_html() . '</div>';
```

This will add star rating below product title. [See more at here](https://community.theme.co/forums/topic/star-rating-woocommerce/).

With above solution, I'm not sure about that so if you want to go with your risk.

You can put this into your themes `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_print_stars' );


function my_print_stars(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
    AND meta_value > 0
");

$rating = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
");

if ( $count > 0 ) {

    $average = number_format($rating / $count, 2);

    echo '<div class="starwrapper" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';

    echo '<span class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__('Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce'), $average).'"><span style="width:'.($average*16).'px"><span itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</span> </span></span>';

    echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

Note that you may need to change '`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`' to a different hook depending on your design and where exactly you want the stars to show up.

For more detail please check [wooCodex](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/woocodex/).

Hope this help you well!

Comment: thanks for your reply.  i tried both code for rating but none is showing :( no idea why.  do you any other soultion or is there any setting which i am missing. i already google long time but not getting any solution . exmple this is nice way http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/product/brooklyn-long-sleeve-sweater/

Comment: thanks. code is working fine. i found out what's the problem. problem was may be data. when i insert product again then it is working fine. but i dont know why it was. i was dump data from another live website

Comment: Cheers. Glad to help!